# Notifications in iOS HomeScreen Webapp

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, alarm

I have a React-based website with PHP backend where users can subscribe to tasks and each task has many subtasks. Sub-tasks must be completed at pre-defined precise times (e.g. Subtask 1 at 8:45, Subtask 2 at 9:57, ...).

The goal is to send some kind of notification with sound to the user's phone at the appropriate times.

As I know from iOS 16.4 it is possible to manage notifications from a home screen web app.
I was able to create the home screen app and subscribe to the notification process. I can find my webapp in the notification center. This is good so far, but what next? But it might not work anyway according to this [No sound for PWA / web app notifications in iOS 16.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75910612/no-sound-for-pwa-web-app-notifications-in-ios-16-4)

Any chance of this working (even in iOS 17) or any other idea on how to notify the user?

(I can not create a native app, I need a webapp solution.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No sound for PWA / web app notifications in iOS 16.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75910612/no-sound-for-pwa-web-app-notifications-in-ios-16-4)